retaining wall calculation and estimation
I have a 17" thick retaining wall which is leaning.
I measured 3 points today:

33" high, 6 degree leaning, outward offset top to bottom 3.5", abbuted to lawn, no load bearing;
36" high, 8 degree leaning, outward offset top to bottom 4.5", abbuted to house, distance to house 6 ft or less, heavy load bearing;
39" high, 3.7 degree leaning, outward offset top to bottom 3.5", abutted to sunroom, less load bearing;
The retaining wall has minor cracks and was leaning over 15 years. I owned this house for 2 years so far.

I want to know if I can mitigate it without replace it. I am thinking about digging out 3 ft to wall then fill with gravel, geo grid + 3 drains(top, bottom and middle), it needs to drain to the street because the other side is my neighbor's drive way without any drain trench. I am also looking for the formula of calculation and prediction of the leaning speed, to predict the speed of leaning seems not very straight forward but I want to calculate by hand and predict it.
I found this v3 rule https://www.oldhouseweb.com/how-to-advice/above-ground-masonry-walls.shtml#:~:text=A%20wall%20is%20usually%20considered,event%2C%20consult%20a%20structural%20engineer.
Seems like it's not violating the V3 rule yet.
Before I figure out i will keep monitoring the leaning.
Thanks in advance.


Your link is for above ground masonry, not for retaining walls.  Not sure of the accuracy of your measurements with the placement of the ruler. What is the actual problem you're dealing with?  That doesn't look bad for 15 years. You'll  need a lot more information before predicting anything.

my problem is the leaning caused collapse will damage my neighbor's property, cars, or personnel. The leaning raises my neighbor's concern over years. He talked to previous owner but previous owner didn't take any action. Now I divert all rain water to the surface, 10 ft away from the house, I plan to divert 20 ft away. I live on a slope so the underground water will pass my house's foundation and flow down. my downspout extender might not help too much.

Are you sure the wall is your property?  What is the approximate height of the wall, and the distance from the toe of the wall to the neighbor's house?  Does the neighbor's house have a basement, or is it slab on grade?

his house has fieldstone foundation and basement. the wall was built on the property line seen from GIS map. The wall tapered from 33" tall to 39" tall. The land has grading and my house is on higher slope.
